# File.Copy vs Stream.CopyToAsync

Tags: c#, winapi, wcf, производительность, filestream

Подскажите пожалуйста, что более правильно использовать для копирования файла в полностью асинхронной службе WCF?

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName: full_path_temp_file, destFileName: 
full_path_file);
```

или

```
await stream.CopyToAsync(destination: file_stream);
```

Я смотрел код на https://referencesource.microsoft.com для обоих методов, File.Copy реализован через вызов WinAPI т.е. полностью неуправляемый код в отличии от Stream.CopyToAsync, но к сожалению File.Copy не асинхронный, т.е. он заблокирует такой важный для WCF ресурс как поток, и в целом это может отрицательно сказаться на производительности службы.

Comment: А что говорит против использования Async-варианта?

Comment: CopyToAsync это последовательность вызовов ReadAsync и WriteAsync с последующим вызовом соответствующих WinAPI, что теоретически на больших файлах должно иметь меньшую производительность чем File.Copy с единственным вызовом WinAPI CopyFile

Comment: Ну, тогда вопрос к вам, вам нужна экстремальная производительность или нет? То есть наверное есть какая-то неоптимальность в async-варианте, но я не думаю, что она значительна по сравнению с накладными расходами на работу с файловой системой.

Comment: То есть провести профилирование обоих вызовов нам невозможно, потому что мы не знаем, какие у вас типичные данные. Я бы посоветовал вам оттестировать на типичных для вашего приложения размерах файлов и нагрузках на файловую систему обе функции, убедиться, что они показывают одинаковое время, и выбрать асинхронный вариант :) Ну или если вдруг окажется, что асинхронный вариант реально на ваших данных намного медленнее, то ещё подумать.

Comment: В ваших словах есть рациональное звено, почему то я не подумал над тем что файловая система заведомо медленнее чем исполнение любого кода в памяти... Наверное сейчас бы я уже не задал вопрос, а просто выбрал async вариант :) Пишите ответ, помечу как правильный? )

Comment: Ну, мой ответ по сути «измерьте сами» :) Давайте напишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Вынесено из обсуждения в комментариях.)

`CopyToAsync` — более общая функция, т. к. она работает с произвольными потоками. Поэтому она теоретически может быть медленнее, менее оптимальной, чем прямой вызов `File.Copy` (например, за счёт другого выбора размеров буфера).

Тем не менее обычно разница незначительна, т. к. операции с файловой системой обычно существенно медленнее операций с потоками и переключениями контекста. А значит, время на обращение и отклик файловой системы должно доминировать в общем времени исполнения функции копирования.

Я бы посоветовал провести профилирование обоих вызовов на типичных для вашего приложения размерах файлов и нагрузках на файловую систему. (Мы, к сожалению, не знаем, какие типичные данные для вашей системы, поэтому наши тесты могут показать не такую производительность, как у вас.) [Только во время профилирования не копируйте один и тот же файл много раз подряд, иначе он окажется в кеше ОС, и результаты профилирования будут неправильными.]

Я бы поставил на то, что обе функции покажут примерно одинаковое время, и в этом случае асинхронный вариант однозначно лучше. Если вдруг окажется, что асинхронный вариант реально на ваших данных намного медленнее, лишь тогда имеет смысл думать о  том, что важнее для вашей программы — не занимать лишний поток или копировать скорее. (А для этого, наверное, нужно снова профилирование — при каком из вариантов мы обслужим больше клиентов за единицу времени?)